# Getting file directory from tkinter function

Tags: python, function, tkinter

I am running a simple python script that opens a window with a button inside of it. When the user clicks the button a dialog box opens and asks the user to select a file directory. I want to pull that directory location out of the function. This is what the code looks like:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog

def openFile():

 filePath= filedialog.askdirectory()
 
 return filePath


window = Tk()

button = Button(text="open", command=openFile)

button.pack()
window.mainloop()
```

I would like the file directory to be saved in a variable inside the window. I am able to print the filepath inside the function but I am unable to bring it out of the function.

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: Define a `class Application` and make `filePath` one of its instance's attributes — then you will be able to easily reference it in any other method of the class.

Comment: Update your code on how you access the filePath out of the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use the return value for functions added to buttons, as there is no way of picking up whatever is returned.

So instead you can write the return to a global variable, or a class variable, instead. Example with global variable below;

```py
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog
my_path = None

def openFile():
    global my_path
    filePath = filedialog.askdirectory()
    my_path = filePath


window = Tk()

button = Button(text="open", command=openFile)

button.pack()
window.mainloop()
```

You will then be able to pick up the `my_path` variable later in your script after clicking the button.

Comment: Hi Oskros I did the following:

from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog

def openFile():
    global my_path
    filePath= filedialog.askdirectory()
    my_path = filePath


window = Tk()
button = Button(text="open", command=openFile)
button.pack()
print(my_path)
window.mainloop()
and I got the following error:
NameError: name 'my_path' is not defined

Comment: because you need to add the `my_path = None` as well, as I did in my example

Comment: @Tamim Don't post code in a comment, edit the original post and add it there.

Comment: @oskros sorry I didn't see that part. So when I added that I was unable to still get the directory as an output. my goal is the store that directory inside a variable between the window and window.mainloop()

Comment: @Tamim I think you misunderstand how tkinter works. When you run the script, the code will pause at the `window.mainloop()` line, and stay there, until you close the UI window. So if you add a `print(my_path)` after the `window.mainloop()`, you will get a print statement when you close the UI window..

Comment: @oskros ah okay yeah that makes sense. So if I wanted the user's input which in my case is the directory they select, I can only access that when I have closed the window?

Comment: @Tamim you can access it from within the UI if you want - for example you could create a label inside the UI that is populated with the path after clicking the button. But yeah if you want to use it in the code later, you need to close the UI first. If I have answered your question, please approve and vote on the answer -thanks